# add class to an element by clicking and remove it to the other elements By JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a menu, and I am trying to add a class to the li when I clik on it, but I need to remove the class to the other li elements when I click on one of them, I have tried this `clicked.classList.remove("active");` but doesnt work, every element I click on get the class and is not possible to remove it, How coud I do this correctly.

Thanks for your help

```js
var menu_link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_option");

for(i=0; i<menu_link.length; i++){
    var clicked = menu_link[i]
    clicked.addEventListener("click", function(){
        clicked.classList.remove("active");
        this.classList.add("active");
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

/*============================================================================
HEADER
===============================================================================*/

header {
    background-color: #ffda00;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

header nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


header .logo {
    font-size: 2rem;
}


header nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/* active menu */

.active {
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
    <title>My Store</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <span class="logo"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your js code a bit. Let's do another loop in your click event listener, to uncheck the "active" class to every menu option.

```js
var menu_link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_option");

for(i=0; i<menu_link.length; i++){
    var clicked = menu_link[i]
    clicked.addEventListener("click", function(){
        // modified in here
        // clicked.classList.remove("active");
        menu_link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_option");
        for (i = 0; i < menu_link.length; i++) {
            menu_link[i].classList.remove("active");
        }

        this.classList.add("active");
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

/*============================================================================
HEADER
===============================================================================*/

header {
    background-color: #ffda00;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

header nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


header .logo {
    font-size: 2rem;
}


header nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/* active menu */

.active {
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
    <title>My Store</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <span class="logo"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you're looking for? if so you can tweak existing code based on this.

you can replace `button` with `li` that won't be an issue.

```js
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Style the active class (and buttons on mouse-over) */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```js
var menu_link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_option");

for(i=0; i<menu_link.length; i++){
    var clicked = menu_link[i]
    clicked.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var active = document.querySelector('.menu_option.active');
        if(active) {
          active.classList.remove("active");
        }
        
        this.classList.add("active");
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

/*============================================================================
HEADER
===============================================================================*/

header {
    background-color: #ffda00;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

header nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


header .logo {
    font-size: 2rem;
}


header nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/* active menu */

.active {
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
    <title>My Store</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <span class="logo"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_option"><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```